# WordPress Update Options

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I am currently creating a WordPress plugin which lists all of the pages within WordPress in the admin settings panel. Each page has a dropdown selection, with a list of options.

The dropdown selection I am using the following code to loop through all pages and using the ID of the page as the value for the option:

```
<select name="field_name" id="field_name">
   <option value="">Please Select</option>
   <?php $page_args = array( 'post_type' => 'page', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'orderby' => 'title', 'order' => 'ASC' ); $page = new WP_Query( $page_args ); ?>
       <?php if ( $page->have_posts()) : while ( $page->have_posts() ) : $page->the_post(); ?>
           <?php $pageID = get_the_ID(); ?>
           <option value="<?php echo $pageID; ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></option>
       <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
   <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
</select>
```

Following that, I have a submit button, that once clicked does the following action:

```
<?php if ( $_REQUEST['field_name'] ) {
        update_post_meta( $_REQUEST['field_name'], 'custom_field_name', $_REQUEST['field_name'] );
        $ok = true;
} ?>
```

Using the above code, this works and submits to the last ID within the list, however I want this to update ALL pages with it's own information.

Does anyone know how I can do a mas "update_post_meta" for all pages within the loop? Ideally, if no changes are made, then it wouldn't do anything at all for that specific page.

Any help would be appreciated.

Many thanks.

Comment: I have updated the question to provide further information...

Comment: Anyone have any ideas about this?